# EF core run method every time row is instantiated

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

So let's say you have an ef core context, and you can grab a list of entities from that context:

```
dbContext.Students.Where(m=>m.score > 70)
```

What is the best way to automatically call a method inside each student object after the data is pulled from the database?  For example, what if the 'Student' class above had a method inside it 'CalculateGrade', how can i make it so that if i were to iterate through these students, the 'CalculateGrade' method was already called?  I'm wondering if there is something i can do in OnModelCreating for example, or perhaps somewhere else.

Comment: can you try adding the method to the constructor? You might need to do .ToList() for the students to be instantiated

Comment: Currently no. Wait for [EFC 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan#lifecycle-hooks) adding [ObjectMaterialized event](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15911).

Comment: i think you're tightly compling business logic with data access that way.

Comment: Yep, that's my question exactly.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this directly on the Student model or create a viewModel and convert the students during the linq call;

```
dbContext.Students.Where(m=>m.score > 70).Select(m=> new StudentViewModel(m))
```

Then in the constructor of that viewModel, you could add the function there.

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
   private bool _isGradesCalculated = false;

   public StudentViewModel(){}

   public StudentViewModel(Student student){
      // store student properties

      calculateGrades();
   }

   public void calculateGrades(){
      _isGradesCalculated = true;
   }
}
```

> the 'CalculateGrade' method was already called"

You could add an unmapped boolean property that is by default = false. Then once `calculateGrades` is called, set that to true.

Comment: Your method would definitely work, but i was hoping to avoid creating a bunch of different DTOs like that honestly.  I think the ObjectMaterializedEvent mentioned above might be what i was looking for